# vue focus goes back to the original input

Tags: vuejs2

I have custom directive focus and I only applied it on my first input

```
input v-focus v-model="fields.code" type="text
input v-model="fields.name" type="text"
```

the focus is doing ok, but when I try to edit the next field the focus changes on the first field

Here is my directive:

```
componentUpdated: function(el, binding){
     el.focus();
}
```

Any suggestion on how can I make this work?

Comment: Can you create a fiddle for it?

Answer (score 0):

It's because the `componentUpdated` hook is being called every time the first input is being updated including when you're leaving it and trying to edit the second one. Use the `inserted` hook instead:

```
inserted: function(el, binding){
    el.focus();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have no tested but just reading Lukasz suggestion looks right. In fact there an example in vuejs2 documentation in custom directive guide section.